# issues launching Gazebo

Tags: ros, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting this response in the terminal when attempting to run Gazebo. Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how I may resolve the problem.

```
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 2687, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/tenicho/ros_ws/src/baxter_simulator/baxter_gazebo/worlds/baxter.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/tenicho/.ros/log/5b625bd4-730c-11e6-89ca-08002710caa1/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/tenicho/.ros/log/5b625bd4-730c-11e6-89ca-08002710caa1/gazebo-2*.log

[INFO] [WallTime: 1473040769.872637] [0.093000] Calling service /gazebo/set_model_configuration
Service call failed: unable to connect to service: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243087/issues-launching-gazebo/) by [tenichols](https://answers.ros.org/users/27897/tenichols/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`139` could be a `SEGFAULT` (128 + 11). Common causes for gazebo to `SEGFAULT`: running in a VM, not having proper/correct 3D hw drivers installed, (unstable) CPU overclocks, etc. The second error is just telling you that something is calling a service that doesn't exist anymore.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0